# Iterator, binary !=, no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'T'

Tags: c++

I have this code, which is part of this library https://github.com/Miguel-Deniz/Vector-Implementation/blob/master/Vector%20Implementation/Vector.h

```
template<class T> class vector<T>::iterator
{
public:
    iterator(T* p)
        :_curr(p)
    {}

    iterator& operator++()
    {
        _curr++;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator& operator--()
    {
        _curr--;
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return *_curr;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator& b) const
    {
        return *_curr == *b._curr;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator& b) const
    {
        return *_curr != *b._curr;
    }

private:
    T* _curr;
};
```

When I try to compile it, compiler points at the `operator!=` and says:

> Error  C2678:  binary '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

If this helps, this is how I use this library:

```
vector<wchar_t> v;
v.reserve(0x200);
...
for (vector<wchar_t>::iterator ve = v.begin(); ve != v.end(); ++ve) {
    if (*ve == t) {
        v.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see the problem. Could you post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Not sure, but it appears to be badly broken code, since to compare iterators it should read `return _curr != b._curr;`. The code you have is comparing what the iterators point to, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Random code that you find on github is more likely to be broken than not. What made you decide that that particular implementation was worth using instead of the standard vector?

Comment: The code you linked to has other problems, for instance here `template<class T>
inline void Vector<T>::resize(int newsize, T val)
{
 reserve(newsize);

 for (int index = _size; index < newsize; ++index)
  _elements[i] = T();

 _size = newsize;
}` `i` is an undeclared variable. Also I notice that in your code it's `vector` whereas the linked code is `Vector`, so clearly the linked code isn't the code you are using. You should post the real code otherwise everyone is just wasting their time.

Comment: Having fixed the errors above, and one other unrelated compilation error, I cannot reproduce the problem you see. As I said post your real code.

Comment: @john , there is `vector` instead of `Vector` because I renamed it, so that I can quickly switch between one vector library and another. Please tell what exactly you changed, I'm trying to make a minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @woopwoop399 In the code above I changed `i` to `index`. In the constructor I changed `:_size(s), _elements(new T[s], _space(s))` to `:_size(s), _elements(new T[s]), _space(s)`

Comment: Other problems: `const iterator cbegin() const;` gives out mutable access. `resize` takes a `T` and ignores it. Distinct lack of members, such as `assign` and `insert`. `Vector<T>::Vector(int s) :_size(s), _elements(new T[s], _space(s))` hopefully doesn't compile. `Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector & arg)` leaves `_space` uninitialised

Comment: I'll go search for another library then, thanks guys.